# Python TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to implement asyncio in my script. However, I am getting a `TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required` when I call `func()`.

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

class Org(object):
    def __init__(self, TEST_URL):
        self.url = TEST_URL
    
    async def get_catalogs():
        async def fetch_point(session, point_url):
            async with session.get(point_url) as r:
            result = await r.json()
            point = result['data']['point']
            return point
        
        async def fetch_concurrent(urls):
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                tasks = []
                for u in urls:
                    tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(fetch_point(session, u)))

                result = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
                print(result)

        await fetch_concurrent([url1, url2, ....])


def func():
    org = Org('https://dummy.example.com/api/')
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(org.get_catalogs())
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Hi! Your code is not running *per se*, could you please fix it? (current useless class wrapping, indentation, ellipsis on URLs list...) - I am currently trying to solve a similar problem, but cannot help for now as I'm not able to run your code :-/

Comment: I tried to simplify your code, with no change in the function calls, but I could not reproduce the issue. I suspect that the code calling `func` may be the issue; so please complete your code sample if more help is needed :)